# Como eliminar espaços duplicados numa string?

Tags: javascript, string, regex

Tenho a seguinte *string*:

```
var str = "00000.00000  111111111.111111111111  33333333"
```

Preciso remover os espaços extras pra ela ficar assim (apenas com 1 espaço):

```
var str = "00000.00000 111111111.111111111111 33333333"
```

Como devo proceder?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Pode usar uma expressão regular para isso:

```
var str = "00000.00000  111111111.111111111111  33333333"
str = str.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');
```

Dividindo a RegEx e `replace` em partes:

- `\s` - qualquer espaço em branco
- `{2,}` - em quantidade de dois ou mais
- `g` - apanhar todas as ocorrências, não só a primeira
- depois o replace faz a subsituição desses grupos de espaços pelo que fôr passado no segundo parâmetro. Neste caso um espaço simples `, ' ');`

Por curiosidade testei [uma variante com `split`/`join`](http://jsfiddle.net/c722swgL/), mas com RegEx [é mais rápido](http://jsperf.com/replace-multiples-places-in-string).

Comment: Perfeito amigo, obrigado!!

Answer (score 6):

Opção para quem não quer RegEx:

```js
var str = "00000.00000  111111111.111111111111  33333333";
while (str.indexOf('  ') != -1) str = str.replace('  ', ' ');
console.log(str);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/String/CleanSpaces.js).

Answer (score 2):

Tem um jeito bem interessante também que funciona praticamente pra qualquer linguagem. Vale pela curiosidade.

```js
let str = '00000.00000  111111111.111111111111  33333333';

str = str.split(' ').join('<>');
console.log('Passo 1:', str);
str = str.split('><').join('');
console.log('Passo 2:', str);
str = str.split('<>').join(' ');
console.log('Resultado:', str);
```

ou

```js
let str = '00000.00000  111111111.111111111111  33333333';

str = str.replace(/[ ]/g, '<>');
console.log('Passo 1:', str);
str = str.replace(/></g, '');
console.log('Passo 2:', str);
str = str.replace(/<>/g, ' ');
console.log('Resultado:', str);
```

**Obs:** Funciona para 2 ou mais espaços